# Does passing an object as a parameter result in the same level of coupling as having it stored in a field?

Tags: java, observer-pattern, loose-coupling, coupling

```
class ConcreteObserver implements Observer {
    String text;

    public void actualize(Subject subject) {
        this.text = subject.getState();
    }
}
```

In other words, does the code above make my `Subject` coupled to `Observer` in the same way as if I did this?

```
class ConcreteObserver implements Observer {
    String text;
    Subject subject;

    public void actualize() {
        this.text = subject.getState();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

all of the following relationships are counted as coupling:

- association
- aggregation
- dependency
- generalization

so `ConcreteObserver` coupled to the `Subject` in both cases.
(and nothing can be said about stated in the question `Subject`'s coupling to `Observer`)

the second case decouples parent `Observer` from `Subject`,
but IMO explicit dependency is better than faking the scope with implicit.